# How to remove the scrollbar in Terminal.app on Mac OS X 10.6?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, terminal.app

If there is a way. I know iTerm2 has it.

Comment: Setting scrollback to 0 lines doesn't help, just no thumb.

Comment: If program A has a feature, it does *not* mean program B automatically has the same feature too. It has to be added by someone. (And Apple tries its best to avoid [explosion of customization options](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000059.html).)

Comment: Rxvt has `printf '\e[?30l'`; it *might* work in other terminals.

Comment: @grawity Doesn't. I also assume that Apple would put that in the preferences if they added that feature.

Comment: [This hint](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031118180040229) worked until Mac OS X 10.4.x but not anymore.

Comment: @grawity that article is bad

Answer (score 15):

Go to `System Preferences` -> `General` and change `Show scroll bars` to `When scrolling`.

Comment: Thank you. It's a bit weird to set a system-wide setting that affects all programs, but perhaps that's behavior I can get used to.